# Stripe connect doesn't giver error but doesn't create accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am currently working on integrating stripe connect to my app but it isn't working. I don't get any errors when I run it and it asks me to create an account and redirects back to the website but when I check my stripe dashboard, it doesn't show any added accounts. Any help would be appreciated! I looked over their documentation and copied that but I got the same results.

Here is some of my code:

```
class StripeController < ApplicationController
   def connect
       response = HTTParty.post("https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token",
       query: {
         client_secret: ENV["STRIPE_SECRET_KEY"],
         code: params[:code],
         grant_type: "authorization_code"
       }
     )

       if response.parsed_response.key?("error")
           redirect_to welcome_path,
           notice: response.parsed_response["error_description"]
       else
           stripe_user_id = response.stripe_user_id
           current_user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id
           redirect_to mypage_path,
           notice: 'User successfully connected with Stripe!'
       end
   end
end
```

```
module UsersHelper
    def stripe_button_link
        stripe_url = "https://connect.stripe.com/express/oauth/authorize"
        redirect_uri = stripe_connect_url
        client_id = ENV["STRIPE_CLIENT_ID"]
    
       "#{stripe_url}?response_type=code&redirect_uri=#{redirect_uri}&client_id=#{client_id}&scope=read_write"
      end
end
```

```
<% if current_user.stripe_user_id %>
<%= link_to "Go to Stripe Dashboard", stripe_dashboard_path(current_user.id) %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to image_tag("ConnectwithStripe.png", width:"120px", height:"40px"), stripe_button_link %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are not saving the user after setting their `stripe_user_id`. Change `current_user.stripe_user_id = stripe_user_id` to `current_user.update!(stripe_user_id, stripe_user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Before I dive in to your specific code and question I wanted to flag that using OAuth with Express accounts is no longer recommended by Stripe.  You should be [creating Express accounts using the `/v1/accounts` API and using Account Links instead](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts).

With that out of the way, I believe the main issue with your code is that you're using `HTTParty.post` instead of `HTTParty.get`.  When the user is redirected from the OAuth flow back to your website it will be a regular GET request, not a POST.

Once the user is redirected back to your site you need to [use the authorization code in the URL to complete the connection process](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-express-accounts#redirected).  It's not clear if the code for this is missing or was omitted from your question, but you need to do something like this somewhere:

```
response = Stripe::OAuth.token({
  grant_type: 'authorization_code',
  code: 'AUTHORIZAION_CODE_FROM_URL_HERE',
})

# Store the response.stripe_user_id (the Stripe account ID) in your database for use in the Stripe-Account header when making Connect requests
stripe_account_id = response.stripe_user_id
```